# How to disable keycloak for a specific url?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have an end point what is used for authenticating/log in to keycloak so I would like to make this end point open for everyone. So I have thi url that should be reachable for everyone: `http://localhost:8080/auth`

I configured the HttpSecurity:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll();

}
```

I have a controller:

```
@RestController
public class AuthController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/auth")
    public String auth() {
        return "Success !!!";
    }
}
```

But when I try to send a GET request:

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "type": "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException",
    "title": "AccessDeniedException",
    "detail": "Access is denied",
    "status": 500
}
```

The keycloak wants a token... I want this URL to not ask for it, to disable keycloak just for this end point and keep it for others.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Still access denied.

Comment: Yes it is. Access denied.

Comment: Tried it like this and did not work: http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth").permitAll().and().httpBasic();